# iPhone app on iPad without compatibility mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I've developed an iphone only app (so 'Targeted Device Family' is set to iPhone since the beginning of the project) and when I finished I've tried to run it on the iPad just to check if the compatibility mode was working correctly but surprisingly it loads a full screen, without any compatibility mode! 
Of course since it's an iphone app it doesn't look good at all. Can you think of the reason why the targeted device family = iPhone doesn't fire the compatibility mode on the iPad? (I tried on real device and simulators as well).

Comment: Are you using the new Launch Screen File, using this will make you app universal. This is fixed in iOS 8.1

Comment: ah yes, shame...I guess need to go back to have launch screen images :/

Comment: For now yes, Apple is fixing it in some future release. But still there will be people who do not update their devices thus launch images is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 8, there is an issue that when you use the new Launch Screen File, your app will automatically become universal. This issue is solved in iOS 8.1 beta, and therefore this is not a real solution.

For now, you are better off using Launch images in the asset catalog.

Also add the device modifier `~iphone` to the launch file will make sure that the app is not see as an universal app.